# How do I centre post navigation links with images in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm building my own WordPress theme and am really struggling to get post navigation looking right.

I have two images (a 'left/older' arrow and a 'right/newer' arrow) that I want to represent the links to show older or newer posts respectively. The links will be displayed immediately beneath the last post currently shown.

If there are no newer posts (i.e. we're on the front page) I want to show an 'older' arrow link only that should be **centred**, if both newer and older posts are available then I want to show both arrows, again **centred at the bottom of the page**. Finally, if there are no older (i.e. only newer posts) available then I want to show the 'newer' posts arrow **centred**.

Here's an image to illustrate:

[image: desired arrangement of post navigation links]

I've read the docs on posts_nav_links() but I just can't seem to get it right.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php global $wp_query;
if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
<div align="center">
  <div class="previous">
    <?php next_posts_link( '<img src="older post arrow" />' ); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    <?php previous_posts_link( '<img src="newer post arrow" />' ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Really not sure why the question was closed though...